# Are there default OIDs for snmp4j AgentX subagents?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I'm new to SNMP. I'm looking at snmp4j's demo AgentX subagent TestSubagent.java (http://www.snmp4j.org/agentX/doc/org/snmp4j/agent/agentx/subagent/test/TestSubagent.html) on a linux box, and have been able to get it registered as a subagent with the snmpd daemon, but I'm unclear how to add new OIDs or alter the value of the existing OIDs that are registered (the 1.3.6.1.4.1.4976 tree). Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register so called ManagedObjects with the DefaultMOServer instance that is used by the sample. There are two major types of ManagedObject: MOScalar and MOTable.

If you have a MIB, you can let AgenPro generate all necessary code. You will only have to put in the instrumentation code then.